# Is the direct sum of projective covers is the projective cover of the direct sum?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A, B, C$ modules of some algebra. Suppose that $B = A \oplus C$ and $A, B, C$ have projective covers. Is the projective cover of $B$ equal to the direct sum of the projective cover of $A$ and the projective cover of $C$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see for example Lemma 27.2 in Anderson and Fuller's "Rings and Categories of Modules".

To sketch one proof:

Let $P\to A$ and $Q\to C$ be projective covers with kernels $K$ and $L$. To prove that the obvious map $P\oplus Q\to A\oplus C$ is a projective cover, we need to show that $K\oplus L\leq P\oplus Q$ is a superfluous submodule. This follows from the following two simple lemmas:

If $M''\leq M'\leq M$, with $M''$ superfluous in $M'$, then $M''$ is superfluous in $M$. So since $K$ and $L$ are superfluous in $P$ and $Q$ respectively, they are both superfluous in $P\oplus Q$.

The sum of two superfluous submodules is superfluous. So $K\oplus L$ is superfluous in $P\oplus Q$.